# Why isn't my page loading up on Github?

Tags: javascript, html, css, github, gulp

I am trying to point my repo to a custom domain and receiving this error:

> 404 File not found
>
> The site configured at this address does not contain the requested
>   file. If this is your site, make sure that the filename case matches
>   the URL. For root URLs (like http://example.com/) you must provide an
>   index.html file.

Here is my repo: https://github.com/rohithpalagiri/rohithpalagiri.github.io

Here is the custom url: rohithpalagiri.com

I looked at my namecheap setting and it was set up correctly. Does anyone know if it's something in my code that's causing the issue?

Answer (score 8):

It currently takes the `master` branch.

Go in the [repo settings](https://github.com/rohithpalagiri/rohithpalagiri.github.io/settings) and choose the `gh-pages` branch. Then click <kbd>Save</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: The option to change it is grayed out, do you know how I can change it so the option is available?

Comment: Simply create a branch with another name. Otherwise, keep the HTML in the master branch and move the code which generates it in another branch.

Comment: Sorry I should have bee more specific, I already have a gh-pages branch but for some reason it's still grayed out and I can change it from master.

Comment: Exactly. You don't need the gh-pages branch since it's a profile page. Just put the content in the master branch.

Answer (score 6):

Hi you don't actually need a `gh-pages` branch for this repo, since you are using `username.github.io`, your master branch will do just fine. Think of github as the directory you are serving from, and it cannot find your `index.html` - it doesn't know to search inside of your `build/` or `src/` directories for it. So you could just have your `index.html` open in the repo and link from there, or pull your build out and make that your repo. Your master branch will work just fine, and keep the `cname`

Answer (score -1):

I have found the same issue. Please check whether your repository contains an index.html file or not. If not, go to that folder and type `git add index.html`.

after that `git commit -m "your commit name"`, and then `git push` and then check on your repository you will find

Answer (score -1):

Change the name of your index html for instance I had named mine portfolio.html then I renamed it to index.html and it solved the issue. Go to file save as and then change the name.