# Page does not pull up on github?

Tags: javascript, html, css, git, gulp

I am trying to point my repo to a custom domain and receiving this error:

> 404 File not found The site configured at this address does not
>   contain the requested file. If this is your site, make sure that the
>   filename case matches the URL. For root URLs (like
>   http://example.com/) you must provide an index.html file.

When inspecting element I receive this error as well:

> Refused to load the image 'http:/rohithpalagiri.com/favicon.ico'
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "img-src data:".

Here is my repo: https://github.com/rohithpalagiri/rohithpalagiri.github.io
Here is the custom url: rohithpalagiri.com

I looked at my namecheap setting and it was set up correctly. Does anyone know if it's something in my code that's causing the issue?

Comment: How's this question different from [your last](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39837559/why-isnt-my-page-loading-up-on-github)?

Comment: Added the actual error

Comment: You should modify your original question, not post another new one.

Comment: Please don't destroy content on Stack Overflow.